# Dynamic AD Group based on Country Code

Tags: powershell, active-directory

We are looking to create a Powershell script that will automatically sort our user base by Country Code into two AD groups, one for English speakers, and one for French speakers.  We are having challenges in getting this to work.

Each account should only be on one list, based on their country.  The original source list of members for our list is Staff All, and we are looking into having two groups, one called Staff All EN, and the other called Staff All FR.  It should also be able to exclude those in a Disabled OU for accounts that are no longer valid. (see below)

This is what we have so far:

```
$frenchCC = Get-Content .\CCFrench.txt
$staffAll = "CN=Staff-ALL,OU=Internal,OU=DistributionLists,OU=SFCG,DC=sfcg,DC=org"
$staffAllEn = "CN=Staff ALL EN,OU=Internal,OU=DistributionLists,OU=SFCG,DC=sfcg,DC=org"
$staffAllFr = "CN=Staff ALL FR,OU=Internal,OU=DistributionLists,OU=SFCG,DC=sfcg,DC=org"

$Target = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $staffAll
```

We have tried several different approaches. The idea is to populate the French list from the AD based on the country code list. Populate the Staff-EN by copying the Staff-ALL list and then removing everyone in the French list.
And somewhere in the process, Remove everyone who is in HR-Disabled.

```
foreach ($Person in $Target) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $staffAllEn -Members $Person.distinguishedname -confirm:$false
}

foreach ($Country in $frenchCC) {
    Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $staffAllFr -Members (Get-ADUser -Filter '"$country"' -eq '") -confirm:$false
}

foreach ($Country in $frenchCC) {
    Remove-ADGroupMember "Staff-ALL-EN" -Members (Get-ADUser -Filter $Country) -confirm:$false
}

$searchOU = Specify the OU where your groups are here (OU=Groups,DC=domain,DC=local)
Get-ADGroupMember Staff-ALL-EN -Properties Disabled | Remove-ADGroupMember Staff-ALL-EN
Get-ADGroupMember Staff-ALL-FR -Properties Disabled | Remove-ADGroupMember Staff-ALL-FR
```

In the source file for the country code,  we have put the country codes in single quotes, double quotes and no quotes. with no difference.

This has really caught us in a pickle.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the content of `CCFrench.txt`?

Comment: CCFrench.txt is a list of french speaking country codes.

Comment: Do your AD users have an a country code attribute?

Comment: Yes, all users have a country code attribute.

Comment: Just to be certain, are the codes in your CCFrench.txt the numeric country codes listed in [ISO 3166](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/standards/country_codes.htm) or the two letter country codes from the same standard?

Comment: Also, your `Get-ADUser` filter is generally wrong. You have a variable contained in a single quoted string, so it won't expand Then you mix and match single and double quotes for the second part after the `-eq`. Plus even if you put the right quotes in and it did work, you would be filtering for something like "Find all users where the FR property is null" and no user is going to have a FR property. What you want is `Get-ADUser -Filter "CountryCode -eq $Country"` to find all users where the CountryCode property matches the `$Country` iteration.

Comment: To further my first comment, you may benefit from [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677987(v=vs.85).aspx) explaining what properties to use for what kind of country code you have.

Comment: Thanks so much TheMadTechnician...will try this and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work on the following for Brad, but I am not being able to make it run for each line in the text files (ex: multiple country codes). Anyone know what to change?

```
$frenchCC = Get-Content .\Countries.txt
$OUs = Get-Content .\OUs.txt
$userListFR = Get-ADUser -Filter {country -eq $frenchCC} -SearchBase $OUs -SearchScope OneLevel
$userListEN = Get-ADUser -Filter {country -ne $frenchCC} -SearchBase $OUs -SearchScope OneLevel
foreach($user in $userListFR) {add-adgroupmember "Staff-ALL-FR" -Members $user}
foreach($user in $userListEN) {add-adgroupmember "Staff-ALL-EN" -Members $user}
```